# Sending to a copied Socket

Tags: c#, sockets

Consider the following:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

// ...

private static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult AR) {

    Socket socket;
    try {
        socket = serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
    } catch (ObjectDisposedException) {
        return;
    }

    socketManager.addSocket(socket);
    // ...

}

// ...
```

Where `socketManager()` is an object of a class I made to manage the sockets (clients).`SocketManager` also has the function `getSocket()` that basically returns a socket based on an ID. So, if I later do something like this:

```
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Some text to send");
socketManager.getSocket(2).Send(data);
```

This will never send "Some text to send" to the client. Is this because I copy `socket` when I do `socketManager.addSocket(socket);`? How can I copy `Socket` objects and still be able to use them properly and send messages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure socket object is pointing to an end point by printing `socket.RemoteEndPoint.ToString()`
If this is fine, then continue by checking `socketManager.getSocket(2).RemoteEndPoint.ToString()`
If this doesn't return the same value, it means that you have to review your socket manager. You should pass it by reference.

Comment: Doesn't C# copy object references by default?

Comment: Just tested the `RemoteEndPoint` and they are both the same.

Comment: By default, the value of the reference is passed, but not the reference itself, so it's not the same object. Since the RemoteEndPoint is the same, I assume the objects have the same values (copy of each other). If it is passed by ref, changing a value to one, would affect the other. Try 'socket.Send(data)' does it work directly on the object?

Comment: Yes, it does work if I use the object I get from the callback `socket.Send(data)`.

Comment: Exactly, this means socketManager.getSocket(2) is a copy of the socket object, so it doesn't behave in the same way. Try modifying and passing it by ref into the socket manager (addSocket(ref socket)).

Comment: Yeah, `ref` is what I needed